# Capistrano 3 hangs in git:check

Tags: ssh, git, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy to a new ubuntu 14.04 box with `cap staging deploy`, but capistrano hangs during the `git:check` task:

`GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/<app_name>/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:<github_user>/<app_name>`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this was due to having changed the port number of ssh in `/etc/services`

Debug steps in case others have similar problems:

First I ran:

`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1  git ls-remote git@github.com:<github_user>/<app_name>`

In the debug, the following line was hanging:

`trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''<github_user>/<app_name>'\'''`

Then I tried:

`ssh -vvv git@github.com`

and in the debug I saw that ssh was trying to connect to a non standard port.